# UseEffect is empty in the beginning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I m traying to create a component using Hooks.
Inside useEffect I call a function, but it dosen 't work. I think is because when the app starts the props is empty and in the second, when is full dosen 't call the function again..
WHY I m doing wrong?
Thanks (sorry for my bad english)

this is the code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const fetchContent = async content => {
  console.log(content) // is empty in the first console, and full in the second.
  const data = [];

  for await (const item of content) {
     data.push({ componentName: item.nombre});
  }
  return data;
};

function ContentGroups(props) {
  const [contentResult, setResult] = useState([]);

   useEffect(() => {
     fetchContent(props.info).then(data => setResult(data));
     console.log(contentResult) // is empty in the first console, and full in the second.
  }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
       {contentResult.map((el, index) => {
        switch (el.componentName) {
          case "top":
            return <h1>soy un top words</h1>/*
        }
      })}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: The `console.log()` should be within the `then.()` block too

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a props dependency in your `useEffect` deps array:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetchContent(props.info).then(data => setResult(data));
}, [props.info]);
```

> Why your example not working?

First, you logging your data while `setState` is async, `console.log(contentResult)` will log the current state before the update.

Secondly, you run your `useEffect` with empty dep array which means you run it once on the component mount.

Answer (score 1):

`console.log` prints before getting the result

```js
useEffect(() => {
  fetchContent(props.info).then(data => {
    setResult(data);
    console.log(data);
  });
}, []);
```